# How to cast superclass instance to subclass instance? (Doctrine)

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm

I would like to use `Class Table Inheritance`:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"player" = "Player", "admin" = "Admin"})
 */
class User
{
    // ...
}

/** @Entity */
class Player extends User
{
    // ...
}

/** @Entity */
class Admin extends User
{
    // ...
}
```

My question is:

If I have a Collection of `User`s, how is it possible to check, which one is an `Admin` and which one is a `Player`. And how to call a method of the subclass after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you manage to get a collection of `Users`?

Doctrine instantiates concrete classes of `Player` and `Admin` depending on value of `DiscriminatorColumn`. You can check which entity you get with `instanceof`:

```
switch(true){
    $entity instanceof Player:
         // do player's stuff
         break;
    $entity instanceof Admin:
         // do admin's stuff
         break;
}
```